# How to prevent Wordpress CodeEditor adding fake </div> closing tags that corrupt the page?

Tags: html-editor

I'm trying to make some trivial HTML changes to a page's source - this should take 10 seconds - but every time I save anything in the code-editor, Wordpress corrupts it by inserting an increasing number of fake `</div>` closing tags.

The tags were NOT mismatched to start with - very easy to insert an open-div and a paired closed-div - wordpress deletes my close tag, moves it to be adjacent to the open-tag.

(the change I'm trying to make: wrapping a gutenberg block in a div, and then positioning that div, since gutenberg is still missing a lot of basic CSS positioning controls)

EDIT: to be clear, if I do something as simple as "let's take this Gutenberg Group block, and try to "float" it using CSS, by wrapping it in a DIV" ... wordpress corrupts the saved HTML.

EDIT2: Gutenberg is still missing many (most?) of the basic CSS/HTML positioning controls. I found a large number of buggy expensive 3rd party plugins that try to add things as basic as "float", or "position: relative". I don't want to insert large amounts of broken code when it can be done in less than 3 seconds with CSS :).

Comment: Are you creating a HTML block that has opening divs but no closing divs, then inserting a second HTML block further down the page that has closing divs but no opening divs? Was there a reason you didn't use a group block with a class name? That would have given you a `<div>` tag with a class name or ID you could target to position with CSS

Comment: Further experiments: if I pick any gutenberg block, and wrap it in open/close DIV tags ... wordpress corrupts it, deletes the close-tag, puts a close tag next to the open tag.

Comment: ... suggesting that: gutenberg simply cannot be used with HTML. I had (incorrectly?) believed that Wordpress still supported HTML editing, but this appears to no longer be the case: the presence of any gutenberg blocks prevents the use of HTML.

Comment: Re: "was there a reason you didn't use a group block with a class name?" ... Only that it's much more complicated and harder to maintain. Requires keeping copies of code in different places (the CSS for layout - which is intrinsic to the layout - is now stored separately from the layout), that if they get out of synch the page will be corrupt. And gutenberg won't understand how to render it in WYSIWYG mode, so it seemed all downside no upside. But if that's the 'correct' way to solve these things in future I'll do it.

Comment: that is the canonical method, HTML blocks are intended to be self contained, the block editor isn't a HTML document editor. You can add class names and IDs to insert additional CSS rules separately without incorporating them into the document itself. I'm also guessing you're on a single site and an administrator, or a multisite as a super-admin? If so you've probably not noticed the you have the `unfiltered_html` capability, which will be disastrous when a non-admin user saves the post and all your bespoke custom HTML gets stripped out by security filters

Comment: if so, it's very likely certain checkboxes are checked in the settings area about balancing tags, but either way what you're doing is going to be fragile and easy to break. You may want to look into block variants, block styles, and editor stylesheets, you could use that to provide a variant of the group block or a style for that block which implements your desired positioning

Comment: Which "settings area" should I be looking at? There's nothing like that in the admin Settings, and nothing in the gutenberg editor settings

Comment: "WordPress should correct invalidly nested XHTML automatically" is an option, but fundamentally what you tried to do shouldn't work. At best that option _might_ allow you to save it and have the markup saved as you wrote it. HTML blocks are not the solution you were hoping they would be